# Multiplicity of roots of polynomial with rational coefficients decidable?

Tags: polynomials, computability, constructive-mathematics

From the standpoint of intuitionistic logic, multiplicity of roots of generic polynomial is uncomputable due to the inability to compare two real numbers. Even though the roots themselves are computable.

A real number in this context it a regular Cauchy sequence:

$$ x: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}, |x(n) - x(m)| \leq \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{m} $$

What if the coefficients of the polymonial are rational numbers?

I mean, if $p(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x^i$, then all the roots (including the complex ones) $x_i, i=1, \ldots n$ are computable. Is it then decidable that $x_i = x_j \lor x_i \neq x_j, i \neq j = 1, \ldots n$?

Comment: What do you mean to compute: the multiplicity of a given root or whether there are any multiple roots. In either case it is also relevant whether you are considering only rational roots, or arbitrary (complex) roots.

Comment: To (probably) change the subject, if we are given the coefficients explicitly, there is an algorithm for determining whether there are multiple roots, and the associated multiplicities.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You mean multiplicity of each root can be found? I think the addendum is important.

Comment: The sequence of multiplicities can be found by using the Euclidean Algorithm on the polynomial and its derivative (and if necessary higher derivatives).

Comment: @ValerySaharov: From my point of view the fact that the theory of algebraically closed fields of characteristic $0$ is decidable settles things. The general algorithm one gets from the theorem is not the efficient one for this problem, while the Euclidean Algorithm will be efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of multiple roots is detected by the [Discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) which is expressible in terms of the coefficient of the polynomial. So if the coefficients are rational, the presence of multiple roots is decidable.

*Edit:* I didn't get the OP's question properly in the first place. Concerning the computation of multiplicities once a complete list of zeros is given, it suffices to note that the set $\overline{{\mathbb Q}}\subset{\mathbb C}$ of algebraic numbers is (constructively) a field and has decidable equality. You can find this for example in the introductory chapter of *Foundations of Constructive Mathematics* by Michael J. Beeson.

Comment: @ValerySaharov Oh, I see - I added an alternative.